# jquery/ajax infinite scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

I'm trying to make my own infinite scroll using ajax, php, mysql on my web app. However I can't find a way to load the new content each time the user is a the end of the page.

For now it loads all the data as soon as the user hit the end of the page.

Is there any way to make my script 'wait until the end of the last page loaded'.

```
$( ".places-wrapper ").scroll(function(){

var windowHeight = $( ".places-wrapper" ).height();
var documentHeight = $( ".places-wrapper")[0].scrollHeight;
var scrollFromTop = $( ".places-wrapper" ).scrollTop();
var margin = 70;

if( scrollFromTop >= documentHeight - windowHeight - margin){

loadNextPage();

}

function loadNextPage(){

    var PlaceID = $( "input[name='placeID']:last" ).val();
    var lastHitDate = $( "input[name='hitDate']:last" ).val();

    $.ajax({
        # .append the new stuff
           });

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is a flag to tell your script that a page is loading.
You may try this approach:

```
// add a variable as flag
var isLoading = false;

if( scrollFromTop >= documentHeight - windowHeight - margin){

     if ( !isLoading )
     {
        isLoading = true;
        loadNextPage();
     }    
}


// inside your ajax's success callback:

.success(function(){
    isLoading = false;

    // add the page contents
})
```

Comment: @gtgye, thanks, however I still face the same problem. It's because of this line `scrollFromTop >= documentHeight - windowHeight - margin` which active the event so many times.

Answer (score 0):

As you propably guessed you need an external variable that turns the "load further places"-switch on and off.

```
var scrollActiveTimer = false;

$(".places-wrapper").scroll(function(){

    // Don't continue if a previous ajax request is still active
    if(scrollActiveTimer == true){
        return;
    }

    // For an improved performance you should try to minimize the jquery DOM searches    
    var wrapper = $(".places-wrapper");
    var windowHeight = wrapper.height();
    var documentHeight = wrapper[0].scrollHeight;
    var scrollFromTop = wrapper.scrollTop();
    var margin = 70;

    var scrollEndPosition = documentHeight - windowHeight - margin;

    if( scrollFromTop >= scrollEndPosition){
        loadNextPage();
    }

    function loadNextPage(){
        // Disable the loading of further pages for the moment
        scrollActiveTimer = true;

        var PlaceID = $("input[name='placeID']:last").first().val();
        var lastHitDate = $( "input[name='hitDate']:last" ).val();

        // Activate the loading event again
        scrollActiveTimer = false;

         $.ajax({
             // parameters..
         }).success(function(data){
             // copy data into html
             wrapper.append(data);

             // Activate the loading event again
             scrollActiveTimer = false;
         });
    }

});
```

I made a fiddle with some dummy functions to simulate the ajax request and html generation: http://jsfiddle.net/Macavity/f77xmho7/2/